# Having difficulty add a custom icon to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe

I have been trying to change the icon in the frame. I have virtually tried everything:

- The icon is 16x16 which is the right size ....doesn't work
- I've trying PNG,GIF and JPG formats none of them work.
- Tried different way of setting the icon....doesn't work.
- I've tried relative (local paths) e.g. "icon.gif" and absolute paths e.g. "c:\work\java\icon.gif" ...doesn't work

Here is my code and see if you can figure it out
Thanks
Oli

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class androidDriver 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Android Data Viewer");
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.setSize(300,300);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("androidIcon2.gif").getImage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: *works for me* (if I add in `java.io.` before `IOException`. Are you running it straight from the command line, or some IDE gubbins?

Comment: where exactly is the image?  The code you have posted will look for the image in the same directory as it is *run* from

Comment: yes the image, class and java file are all in the same location

Comment: I have added:

        File file = new File(directory1 +"\\androidIcon2.gif");
        System.out.println(file.exists());

and True was printed out meaning it knows the file is there

(directory1 is user.dir)
String directory1 = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Answer (score 1):

If you put the image in the same directory as the class file then the following should work for you:

```
        f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(androidDriver.class.getResource("androidIcon2.gif")).getImage());
```

Also would suggest setting the icon image *before* you make the frame visible

```
        f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(androidDriver.class.getResource("androidIcon2.gif")).getImage());
        f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: The first solution came up with null pointer exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:138)
        at androidDriver.main(androidDriver.java:24)
Java Result: 1

Tried Second solution but did nothing

Comment: that suggests it cannot find the image. whats your classpath set to?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have to actually wait for the image to load using a MediaTracker.  It's likely that the image is still loading at the point the frame setIconImage references it, so it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("androidIcon2.gif")

And two other things:

1. Does the image exist? The code you posted will fail silently.
2. Is it formatted properly? (though I assume Java could handle it if it wasn't)

Comment: yes it does exist, added file.exists() and true was printed out      
Yes - Java documentation says it need to be 16x16 and either a GIF, JPG or PNG

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate folder next to the source folder then put your image in there, and then use ImageIO to get the image like so:

```
f.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("res/androidIcon2.gif")));
```

Also, if that doesn't work, try saving the image as a .png instead of a .gif.